# What's the difference between "keeping hope" and "keeping good hope"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What's the difference between "keeping hope" and "keeping good hope"? I heard both, but unlike in case of the difference between "faith" and "good faith", the latter of which doesn't even imply faith, I can't see the difference and can't find any explanation to this in Webster.

Comment: Idiomatically, you can ***keep faith***, but it's not idiomatic to speak of ***keeping hope***. If you heard that, it was from other nns, or people with "non-standard" ideas about how to use these expressions.

Comment: (Note that *to keep faith* means *to honour one's commitment*. It's not really got much to do with the sense of *faith = belief*.)

Comment: I can think of some contexts where "keeping hope" might be used, such as "Keeping hope in our hearts during the surgery" or something, but I can't think of any contexts for "keeping good hope".

Comment: On the other hand, it's perfectly natural to tell people to *keep* ***hoping***. (However, *good hoping* is not used.)

Answer (score 0):

**To keep hope** means not to lose hope.  However the phrase "Keep hope!" isn't used much any more. It is a 19th century locution. Nowadays we say "Don't lose hope!".